# Can I add an object key to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am going through the javaScript course on codeacademy.com and I noticed that I couldn't do this:

```
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.name = 'Jack';
myObj.age = 24;
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[myObj.name, myObj.age]];
```

the array had to be

```
[[1,2,3],[myObj]]
```

Is this just how it works with javaScript or is it just a limitiation in the course?

Comment: `[[1,2,3],[myObj.name, myObj.age]];` should work, it would produce  `[[1, 2, 3], ["Jack", 24]]`. Without knowing what the lesson was on, it is hard to tell what they were expecting.

Comment: Output should be `Array [ Array[3], Array[2] ]` or `[[1,2,3],['jack', 24]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. There will be no error thrown if you will execute these statement.

When you will do `console.log(myArray)` it results `[[1, 2, 3], ["Jack", 24]]`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjafo88g/)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a limitation in the course. Doing:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[myObj.name, myObj.age]];
```

Is perfectly valid as it's the same thing as doing:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],["jack", 24]];
```

Your course is just expecting output to be in the form of:

```
[[1,2,3],[myObj]]
```